# Can not detect keyboard language (layout) in raspbian

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, raspberry-pi, xlib

I have two threads working with keyboard. Each thread maybe changes the keyboard mapping and the other must be notified by this change. To recognize the change in keyboard language I have written the following function :

```
char getKeyboardLang(Display *dpy)
{
    int baseEventCode, baseErrorCode, opcode;
    int groupCount;
    int major = XkbMajorVersion;
    int minor = XkbMinorVersion;


    XkbQueryExtension(dpy, &opcode, &baseEventCode, &baseErrorCode, &major,
            &minor);
    XkbDescRec* kbdDescPtr = XkbAllocKeyboard();

    if (kbdDescPtr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to get keyboard description.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    kbdDescPtr->dpy = dpy;
    kbdDescPtr->device_spec = XkbUseCoreKbd;

    XkbGetControls(dpy, XkbAllControlsMask, kbdDescPtr);
    XkbGetNames(dpy, XkbSymbolsNameMask, kbdDescPtr);
    XkbGetNames(dpy, XkbGroupNamesMask, kbdDescPtr);

    if (kbdDescPtr->names == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to get keyboard description.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Get the group names.
    const Atom* tmpGroupSource = kbdDescPtr->names->groups;

    //printf("%c\n", XGetAtomName(dpy, kbdDescPtr->names->groups[0])[0]);
    return XGetAtomName(dpy, kbdDescPtr->names->groups[0])[0] ;
}
```

This function works perfectly in Ubuntu 14 and 16. It means that after the command `setxkbmap us` this functions returns the character 'E' (English Us) and after the command `setxkbmap ir` it returns 'P' (Persian). But in raspbian (a modified debian fo Raspberry pi board) this function always returns 'E', even after execution of `setxkbmap ir`!

In Ubuntu when I run `setxkbmap ir`, the language of keyboard changes to persian and the output of `setxkbmap -query` is :

> rules:      evdev
>
> model:      pc105
>
> layout:     ir

And the strange thing in raspbian is that after `setxkbmap ir`, the language of keyboard changes to persian BUT the output of `setxkbmap -query` says that it is English us :

> rules:      evdev
>
> model:      pc105
>
> layout:     us

And this way I don't know how could be possible to detect the current  language of keyboard in raspbian in a C program?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this has to do with drivers maybe? Can you try it on debian instead of ubuntu?

Comment: Why are you allocating a keyboard (without freeing it, leak!)? Instead, call `XkbGetKeyboard` and in any case, don't forget to call `XkbFreeKeyboard`.

Comment: @Titulum : Currently I have no access to a debian system. Is there such a difference between ubuntu and debian?

Comment: @iMoses : Thank you for your point :), but have you any idea about the main problem here?

Comment: Sorry @payman but no, I don't. I'd answer instead of adding a comment otherwise.

Comment: @payman I think the differences between Ubuntu and Deban become bigger through the years. When testing software you aim to use in raspbian, maybe try to always test it on a debian system.